# using gSOAP with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gsoap

i would like to use this service with `gSOAP`: ([See Docs](https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula))

i have downloaded the `WSDL` file and `converted/conpiled` it and now i have got the following files:

```
KPSPublic.h
soapH.h
soapStub.h
soapC.cpp
soapClient.cpp
soapClientLib.cpp
soapServer.cpp
soapServerLib.cpp
KPSPublicSoap.nsmap
KPSPublicSoap.TCKimlikNoDogrula.req.xml
KPSPublicSoap.TCKimlikNoDogrula.res.xml
```

From here, i don't know how to go on - or - how to include `gSOAP` to my `QtApplication`.

Please can anyone tell me, how to use this service with `gSOAP` under Qt?

Comment: It is either unclear what you are asking. Are you about some xml usage? Are you about integrating a library handling that for you into your qmake build system, etc? Please clarify.

Comment: i want to use this service with gSOAP: https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula but dunno, how to integrate the source files of gSOAP to my QtApplication, so that no DLL is required.

Answer (score 0):

There at least two ways for avoiding dynamic libraries (i.e. `dll` on Windows):

1) You can build the library statically, and you will use the following `qmake` variables in your project file:

```
LIB += -L/path/to/the/static/library -llibraryname
```

2) You can import all the sources and headers into your project, like "third-party". You will need to hover over the project tree on the left side of QtCreator, and then you will need to use the right mouse click over the desired target folder, and add the headers and sources. You can also edit the qmake project file explicitly, by using the `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` variables. You will need to make sure that all the dependencies are met for that third-party though, so you will need to add them similarly as mentioned in 1).